# Printing Text from Custom Fields added to TFS Test Case Work Item

Tags: xml, xslt, tfs, xsd

We are using TFS2017/2018 not VSTS, so I have access to the server.  I am attempting to print a test plan that contains 3 custom html fields.

Don't hate me...my industry still has a need for hard copy test plans.

I've modified the TestCase.xml and TestSuite.xsl based on an existing field within the work item type that does what I am attempting to do. I have updated the TestCase.xml file and imported it using the witadmin tool. The fields are present and functional on the work item and the data entered in them shows up in the database.  So the fields are defined correctly.

My new fields were based on the existing field on the Test Case Work Item. I basically c/p the summary and modified it to reflect the new fields' information.  The first line of this is where I am stumped.

```
<xsl:for-each select="summary">
  <div class="sub-tab" _locID="Summary">
     SUMMARY
     <br/>
   </div>
   <div>
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </div>
   <br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know it needs to read something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="newFieldvariable">
```

I know that XML/XSL are case sensitive, thus leaving me to believe that the "summary" in the for-each select is defined someplace else. Since it is not defined anywhere in the two files I have modified, I thought perhaps there would be an XSD? I've searched all over the TFS files trying to find an XSD or other place where that variable is defined to allow me to modify that file and populate the custom fields via a similar select statement.

My assumption was further supported by adding

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which listed summary as the local name.

I've googled the poo out of this and I just can't seem to find where that "summary" is defined.

I'm not completely green to coding, but I haven't been working in XML or XSLT in a very long time.  What am I missing?

[Picture of modified work item with custom fields added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axEEn.png)

The information entered in the custom fields need to be displayed on the export.  See image linked below.  Information should display where highlighted in yellow.
[Picture of export Print Preview with new field headers but no info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtESU.png)

Comment: Are you using the old work item form or the new one? About the summary, did you just mean the one alongside steps? Are you trying to custom the name of summary to someone else?

Comment: I am using the new work item form.  The summary information I am referencing it the information displayed on the Summary tab. The information that is actually displayed is the Test Case description.  I have added 3 new fields to that tab. The fields display and can be populated.  The data is showing up in the database.  The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get those new fields to print out on a export despite modifying the XSL file that the export is based on.  This is due in part to not knowing what to put in this line of code '<xsl:for-each select="whatGoesHere">'

Comment: Hi@E.C. Sorry for the later reply, still not totally got your point. Suggest you add a screenshot to make this more clearly. Did you just want to embed some type of text in the description filed or custom 3 new fields to that tab. If so, take a look at this related question to see if it be helpful to you: [Embedding Text in TFS Description Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756908/embedding-text-in-tfs-description-field)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Thank you for checking back.  I have added linked screen shots to the bottom of the original post. The related question you linked will work as a work around, but the company I work for would prefer to have the information separated into separate fields to make it conform to our contractual documentation standards.